# django complex formset issue

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms

I have 3 primary models. Questionnaire model or question set contains set of questions. All user response are stored in answer.

Now I have to generate a formset which will store answer of all questions in a questionnaire set. How can I do it in django. So far I have manged to do it by displaying single question at once from a given questionnaire and store the response. My problem is that based on questiontype use two different modelform (MultipleChoiceAnswerForm,DescriptiveChoiceAnswerForm) and validate them based on the formtype. How can I use it in formset.

I am beginner in django and any help is appreciated.

My Code:

```
#Models.py

class Question(models.Model):
    statement = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    question_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=get_qtypes())
    remarks = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s'%(self.statement)

class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    questionaire_type = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=QUESTIONNAIRETYPE)
    context = models.ForeignKey(QuestionContext)
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tathya_user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s'%(self.title)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    teacher=models.ForeignKey(Person, null=True, blank=True, default = None)
    questionaire = models.ForeignKey(Questionnaire)
    statement = models.CharField(max_length=255)


    def get_label(self):
        return '%s'%(self.question.statement)
    def get_choices(self):
        return get_questionchoices(self.question.question_type)

class DescriptiveAnswerForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DescriptiveAnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            self.fields['statement'].label = kwargs['instance'].get_label()

    statement = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        exclude=('question','person','course','teacher','questionaire')

class MultipleChoiceAnswerForm(ModelForm):
    statement = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=EMPTY,attrs={'class': 'allradio',}))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MultipleChoiceAnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            self.fields['statement'].label = kwargs['instance'].get_label()
            self.fields['statement'].choices = kwargs['instance'].get_choices()

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        exclude=('question','person','course','teacher','questionaire')

###################################################################
#view.py
@login_required
def content_feedback_view_old(request,course_code):
    #do validation and other jobs
    questionnaire = get_questionnaire(some_params_like_coursecode)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        r_answer = Answer()
        r_answer.question = Question.objects.get(id=request.session['question'])
        r_answer.person = student
        r_answer.course = course
        r_answer.questionaire = questionnaire
        r_answer.tathya_user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk)
        rformtype = request.POST['formtype']
        if rformtype == 'MCQ':
            rform = MultipleChoiceAnswerForm(request.POST, instance=r_answer)
        else:
            rform = DescriptiveAnswerForm(request.POST, instance=r_answer)
        if rform.is_valid():
            rform.save()
        else:
           #return HttpResponse(printerror("Some problem occurred!"))
           errortext = "You need to provide an input!"

    questions = questionnaire.questions.all()
    allquestions = questions.count()
    tot_q = 0
    formtype = ""
    answered = 0
    for question in questions:
        try:
            answer=Answer.objects.get(question=question,person=student,course=course,questionaire=questionnaire)
            answered += 1
        except:
            answer = Answer()
            answer.question = question
            answer.person = student
            answer.course = course
            answer.questionaire = questionnaire
            answer.tathya_user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk)
            request.session['question']=question.id
            tot_q = tot_q + 1;
            if get_questiontype(question.question_type)=='MCQ':
                formtype="MCQ"
                form=MultipleChoiceAnswerForm(instance=answer)
            else:
                formtype="DESC"
                form=DescriptiveAnswerForm(instance=answer)
            break
    if tot_q>0:
        data_dict['FeedbackFormType']=formtype
        data_dict['FeedbackForm']=form
        data_dict['pagetitle']=context.description
        data_dict['coursecode']=course.course_code
        data_dict['feedbacktitle']="Content Feedback for "+course.fullname
        data_dict['Completeness'] = (answered/allquestions)*100
        data_dict['error']=errortext
    else:
        return HttpResponse(printerror("Thanks! You've answered all the questions!<br><a href=\"/feedback/teachers/"+course.course_code+"\">Continue with the teaching feedback.</a>"))
    req_context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response('view.html', data_dict, req_context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: only use on single AnswerForm and let it manage which kind of field and widget it should use, ie:

```
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnswerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = self.instance
        if instance.question.question_type == 'MCQ':
             self.fields["statement"] = forms.ChoiceField(
                 choices=instance.get_choices(),
                 widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'allradio',})
                 )
        else:
             self.fields["statement"] = forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.Textarea()
                )
        self.fields['statement'].label = instance.get_label()

    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        exclude=('question','person','course','teacher','questionaire')
```

As a side note, you can pass model's attributes values to the model's constructor:

```
    answer = Answer(
        question=Question.objects.get(id=request.session['question']),
        person=student,
        course=course,
        questionnaire=questionnaire,
        # User.objects.get(id=request.user.pk) will return request.user
        # so it's just useless - just use request.user
        tathya_user=request.user
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem almost solved. Stuck in a different point, but better stick to DIY approach.